# Which parts of ELF format does objcopy parameter --strip-all remove?

Tags: elf, objcopy

I did compile and link my program and i get a format in ELF32 little endian which is build like this:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x11029000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6804 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         16
  Section header string table index: 13

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        11029000 001000 000414 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 001414 000030 00      0   0  1
  [ 3] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 001444 00002a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 4] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 00146e 0000d8 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 001546 00013c 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 001682 00012f 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 0017b1 00005f 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .debug_pubnames   PROGBITS        00000000 001810 000034 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 001844 000020 00      0   0  1
  [10] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 001864 000078 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 0018dc 0000bf 01  MS  0   0  1
  [12] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 00199c 000048 00      0   0  4
  [13] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0019e4 0000b0 00      0   0  1
  [14] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 001d14 000450 10     15  55  4
  [15] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 002164 000244 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x11028000 0x11028000 0x01414 0x01414 R E 0x8000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

There are no unwind sections in this file.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 69 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 11029000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     8: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
     9: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    10: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    11: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
    12: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 
    13: 00000010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_USR
    14: 00000011     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_FIQ
    15: 00000012     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_IRQ
    16: 00000013     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_SVC
    17: 000000d3     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_SVC_NI
    18: 00000017     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_ABORT
    19: 0000001b     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_UNDEF
    20: 0000001f     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_SYSTEM
    21: 0000001f     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MODE_BITS
    22: 00000080     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS I_MASK
    23: 00000040     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS F_MASK
    24: 000000c0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS IF_MASK
    25: 1201c000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS BROM_MMU_BASE_ADDR
    26: ffffeffa     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MMU_DISABLE_MASK
    27: 00001005     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS MMU_ENABLE_MASK
    28: 00000080     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS FIQ_STACK_SIZE
    29: 00000100     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS IRQ_STACK_SIZE
    30: 00000020     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS ABORT_STACK_SIZE
    31: 00000020     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS UNDEF_STACK_SIZE
    32: 00000040     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS SYSTEM_STACK_SIZE
    33: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    34: 11029080     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 arm926ejs_reset_handler
    35: 11029004     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    36: 1102901c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 image_type
    37: 11029020     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 sizeOfPermanentCode
    38: 1102902c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 bootparameter
    39: 11029080     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    40: 110290e8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 inVirtMem
    41: 1102915c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 clearzi
    42: 11029170     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 clearzi_exit
    43: 11029170     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 load_entry
    44: 1102918c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 inval
    45: 11029180     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 flushonly
    46: 11029198     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    47: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS cgu_fractional_divider.c
    48: 110291b4     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    49: 11029300     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    50: 1102930c     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    51: 110293d4     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    52: 110293d8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
    53: 11029410     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    54: 00000010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 $d
    55: 11029414     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __gnu_bssend
    56: 11029414     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __gnu_bssstart
    57: 11029414     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __exidx_end
    58: 00000600     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __image_size
    59: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __exidx_start
    60: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 arm926ejs_reset
    61: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __start
    62: 11029000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __gnu_textstart
    63: 1102930c   204 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 adc_cgu
    64: 11029178     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 dcache_flush
    65: 110291b4   344 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 c_entry
    66: 110293d8    60 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 delay
    67: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ea3131_init
    68: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS __EH_FRAME_BEGIN__

No version information found in this file.
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM926EJ-S"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TEJ
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: small
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

Then i have to use the command below to change my format into binary. That is what i ve heard it does. But can anyone tell me which parts of ELF32 format exactly does parameter "--strip-all" remove and how is binary format then different than ELF32 format?

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -I elf32-littlearm -O binary --strip-all --verbose foo1 foo2
```

I includded my ELF32 format details above soo you can (if it is possible) color the parts which are removed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

binary is pure data and elf is the data in some genral format that describe how to use this data.
elf got a magic, sections, some tables and etc. 
binary is only the data itself/